# EXCEL: Creating graphics controllable by events in spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, graphics, script, vector-graphics, events

I am wondering if there is way to create or import graphics in MS Office Excel, and then control its properties by script.

For example **imagine a map of world on the right hand side and a spreadsheet with countries on the left**, if user would **hover mouse** over a country in spreadsheet it would **change color** in the image. Change of color in this case would be preferably done by calling something like: country_5.outline.color = "#F00", rather than exchanging the country image for a different one, or applying some sort of a filter overlay.

This will not necessarily be the exact case, but i figured once there is way to control properties of an object by functions ran by events triggered by user mouse movements, anything can be done.

**If there is, just poke me in the right direction please.**

Req:
By Script I mean JS, or something with similar syntax.
By Graphic I mean shape of a color with a border of thickness and color.In an ideal case this would be an adobe Illustrator file and  I would be able to access its properties as I am in AI.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note:

1, Excel is not about creating printed-documents or interactive-documents.  Yes, there is some limited capabilities for doing such... but it's more about creating an interface for gathering data and doing some basic number-crunching and doing some basic reporting.  In similar comparison, Adobe Illustrator is about creating printed/presented documents and very little to do with number-crunching & reporting.  There are more specialized tools for every task.  With that being said, here comes #2.

2, there are several ways you can accomplish this using the built in VBA framework (visual-basic for applications).  If you don't know enough about VBA to accomplish this, then you should probably redirect your question towards the programming forums.  Something like this is not a simple undertaking, and not a simple matter of drag & drop.